# in between floated elemnts if we give position relative to any element will it effect to flow of document?

Tags: css

in between lots of floated elements if we give `position:relative` to any element to use position:absolution inside, will it effect to flow of document?

```
FLOAT 1  |  FLOAT 2  |  FLOAT 3 + position relative |  Float 4
```

if i only want to give pixel perfect position to an element inside **Float 3 box** then what should i do? I need compatibility in all browser including IE6

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, it won't. Position relative normally does not affect the flow of the document (siblings) at all unless it is a browser bug. Of course it is meant to affect how a `position:absolute` child is positioned.

`position: relative` is the correct way to allow for an absolutely positioned child element.

Comment: is it compatible to all browser?

Comment: All mainstream browsers, with a valid `DOCTYPE`, yes.

Answer (score 0):

No, `position: relative` won't affect that element's flow, it will just allow you to give child elements absolutely positioned to it, and a few extra tricks (like using z-index to raise it's z stacking index).